# app.get(/) not rendering the index.ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, middleware, referenceerror

I am quite new to node.js. I was just following the basic tutorial for express js. The problem i am facing id I am not able to render the index.ejs file even after following the steps. on hitting localhost I am getting ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at C:\NodeJS\expressDemo.js:28:13

expressDemo.js:

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var path= require('path');

var app = express();
/* var logger = function(req, res, next){
console.log("logging");
next();
}
app.use(logger); */ //middleware

//view engine--ejs

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));

 /* body parser middleware */ 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){

    res.render(index);
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("application started on 3000 port");

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

 res.render("index");
});
```